# How to add a background image inline style to link tag Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I just can't seem to get this right.

In my rails app I am using ActionCable, it has issues with sending over URLs in partials. To fix this I am going to let the CSS do the work of setting the image, only to allow the image to be set dynamically I am going to need to have access to the view hence the fact this has to be inline css.

```
.message
  %a.message_profile-pic{ :href => "", {:style=>"background-image:url('avatar.png')" } }
```

I have an image called avatar.png in my `app/assets/images` directory just as a test. It's an empty a-tag for now but it will become a `link_to` once I sort out the profile sections of the app.

I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
...nd-image:url('avatar.png')" } )}></a>\n  #{
```

How do I set this? I am using Rails 5 rc1 and Ruby 2.3 with bootstrap.

**Note:**

I have also tried the new HAML syntax with the same result:

```
%a.message_profile-pic{ :href => "", style: {background-image: "url('avatar.png')"}}
```

**Edit**

Here is what better errors is showing me:

[image: errors from the gem]

Full stack trace looks like this:

```
    SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
    ...nd-image:url('avatar.png')" } )}></a>\n  #{
    ...                               ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:6: unknown regexp option - a
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:6: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
    ));}\n  </a>\n  <span class='message_timestamp'>\n    #{
                 ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    ));}\n  </a>\n  <span class='message_timestamp'>\n    #{
                               ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:6: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
    ));}\n  </a>\n  <span class='message_timestamp'>\n    #{
                                                     ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tSTRING_DEND
    ));}\n  </span>\n  <span class='m...
        ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:8: unknown regexp options - pa
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
    ...n class='message_star'></span>\n  <span class='message_conte...
    ...                               ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    ...ge_star'></span>\n  <span class='message_content'>\n    #{
    ...                               ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
    ...<span class='message_content'>\n    #{
    ...                               ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:11: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tSTRING_DEND
    ));}\n  </span>\n</div>\n", -2, f...
        ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:11: unknown regexp options - dv
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:11: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
    ));}\n  </span>\n</div>\n", -2, false);::Haml::Util.h...
                            ^
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:11: unterminated string meets end of file
    /Users/ruberto/Personal/Projects/splat/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting tSTRING_DEND:
```

Comment: Can you post the whole line of code where you get the Syntax error? You are missing something syntactically, that is what the error is about!

Comment: The syntax `:href => ""` seems wrong, Should probably  just be  `href: ""`.

Comment: Hi @mahatmanich I tried changing the `href: ""` but it yields the same result.

Comment: What is `{ :href => "", style: {background-image: "url('avatar.png')"}}` ? Is that a proc or a Hash?

Comment: Maybe it is just HAML :-) I never used HAML ...

Comment: Yeah that is HAML syntax, it's a hash. Haml is generally awesome.

Comment: Can you try without the nested hash, i.e.  `%a.message_profile-pic{ :href => "", :style=>"background-image:url('avatar.png')" }`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
:style => "background-image: url(#{image_path "avatar.png"})"
```

To find more about [image_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_path).

Comment: Here is an example in html.erb  (tested in rails 5.2) ```<div style="background-image: url(<%= image_path "avatar.png"%>)"></div>
```